# django templates upload file - how to handle a non-existant physical file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-file-upload

I am using django to upload an image file to the server.

When the user attempts to view a missing image in the django templates, there is just the broken image displayed, but I want to display a default missing image file.

**How do I handle the possibility of the physical file being deleted (or just missing) but the location still stored in the database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.exists) method of the file storage. For example if the name of the image field is `image` the code will look like:

```
if obj.image.storage.exists(obj.image.name):
    ...
```

To simplify things you can create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django.conf import settings

@register.filter
def default_image(image, default_file):
    if image.storage.exists(image.name):
        return image.url
    return settings.STATIC_URL + default_file
```

And then use it right in the template:

```
<img src="{{ obj.image|default_image:'no-image.png' }}" />
```

Comment: catavaran, I am getting the error message `'str' object has no attribute 'storage'`. What import statement must I include in the filter file? Also, I changed `@register.simple_tag` to `@register.filter()`. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Sorry, of course it should be the `@reguster.filter`.  As for the `'str' object...` error I suspect you pass the wrong attribute to the filter.  Show the template fragment where you got this error, please.

Comment: Just to be sure: you should pass the image or file object to the template filter, but not the filename.

Comment: Actually I have been having issues with the template code because the **{{STATIC_URL}}** variable inside the template variable (I am not sure how to structure it) as shown here: `<img src="{{ attachment_detail.attachment_document.url|default_image:'{{ STATIC_URL }}img/attachments/attachment_not_uploaded.png' }}" />`

Comment: Remove the `url` part of the variable and add the `STATIC_URL` in the template filter like in my example: `{{ attachment_detail.attachment_document|default_image:'img/attachments/attachment_not_uploaded.png' }}`

Answer (score 0):

Check the file object using python

```
file_obj = Model.objects.get(id=1)

if os.path.exists(file_obj.file):
    file_path = file_obj.file
else:
    file_path = default_path
```